# AWS Go SDK lambda.Start() compilation error

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I am attempting to create an AWS Lambda with Go, but I am getting an error when compiling. I have already run go get for the lambda dependency and the package resolves, just not the Start method that I see in examples such as: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html

If anyone has any insight as to why this is happening I would greatly appreciate it, thank you. Also, please let me know if there is anything else I can add that would be beneficial in solving this.

**Build error:**

```
➜  main go build
# _/.../aws-lambda-example/src/main
./main.go:27:2: undefined: lambda.Start
```

Similarly, IntelliJ indicates the `Start(...)` method is undefined:

[image: IntelliJ screenshot of unresolved reference]

**Here is the Go code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/lambda"
)

type Request struct {
    ID    int `json:"id"`
    Value int `json:"value"`
}

type Response struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Ok      bool   `json:"ok"`
}

func Handler(request Request) (response Response, err error) {
    response = Response{
        Message: fmt.Sprintf("Request ID: %d, Value entered: %s", request.ID, request.Value),
        Ok:      true,
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

Comment: Your import of the lambda package is quite different from the one in the linked example and from the actual path in the git repo, why?

Comment: It appears that those examples are not up to date with the import. If you go to the actual AWS SDK pages they show the import at the top of the page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/

Comment: Yep that was it @mkopriva thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mkopriva answered this question. I replaced the import in the example as mkopriva suggested:

"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"

This fixed the issue.

Comment: Please accept this answer then. It is allowed to accept your own answers.